# Git alias for checkout branch, pull and checkout back

Tags: bash, git, alias

We are using the Feature-Branch-Workflow, which means others merge theire changes to the `dev`-branch that I want to merge into my feature branch. As it happens a lot I would like to have a simple git alias which does:

1. Checkout the `dev` branch
2. Pull
3. Checkout the previous branch

I want to do the merge myself, as sometimes changes block the checkout or pulls can fail.

My current state is:

```
[alias]
  pull-and-back = !git checkout $1 && git pull && git checkout @{-1}
```

which sadly gives the error `error: pathspec 'dev' did not match any file(s) known to git`.

What is going wrong? I assume as the exclamation mark causes the command to be interpreted as bash code the last part `@{-1}` is not evaluated by git but by bash instead.

Comment: Why not just `git fetch dev:dev` instead of 2 slow checkouts?

Comment: Or, even better, `git fetch origin` and then `git merge origin/dev` for instance. You don't need your own `dev` branch name at all!

Comment: Interesting ideas, reminds me that I never truely understood and used `git fetch`. As far as I understand this downloads the remote commits from the `dev` branch, but does not merge them into my local `dev` branch. This would give me an opportunity to merge the remote branch separately into the local feature branch or local `dev` branch.

I understand how this increases the performance, however I would need to keep in mind that I need to `merge` or `pull` `dev` before using it. Sounds like a big source of confusion to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use an ad hoc bash function to pass your parameter :

```
git config alias.pab '!f() { git checkout $1 && git pull && git checkout -; }; f'
```

As a note, `git checkout -` is a handy shortcut for `git checkout @{-1}`, but both work.